# How to remove all files from GIT repo history with path having colon : in filename?

Tags: linux, windows, git, filenames, repository

I have ISCSI node filenames with colons stored in GIT repository on Debian 10 Linux.

Example:

```
'iscsi/nodes/iqn.2000-01.com.synology:NAS01-DS916.nas/ff11::111:11ff:ff1f:1ff1,3260,1/default'
'iscsi/send_targets/1.2.3.4,3260/iqn.2000-01.com.synology:NAS01-DS916.nas,ff11::111:11ff:ff1f:1ff1,3260,1,default'
```

But checkout fails on Windows, because the colon is invalid character in Windows filename.

I get following GIT errors at Windows checkout:

```
error: invalid path 'iscsi/nodes/iqn.2000-01.com.synology:NAS01-DS916.nas/ff11::111:11ff:ff1f:1ff1,3260,1/default'
...
error: invalid path 'iscsi/send_targets/1.2.3.4,3260/iqn.2000-01.com.synology:NAS01-DS916.nas,ff11::111:11ff:ff1f:1ff1,3260,1,default'
```

**Questions:**

**1) How to list all path having colon : in full GIT repo history?**

**2) How to remove all files from GIT repo history with path having at least one colon : in filename?**

**SOLUTION for 1) :**

Works1:

```
git log --all --name-only -m --pretty= -- '*:*' | sort -u
```

Works2 (only for the named repo master):

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep ":"
```

Works3: Finally I used this to list files with colons in filename:

```
git log --format="reference" --name-status --diff-filter=A "*:*" >/opt/git_etc_repo_files_w_colons.txt
```

**UPDATE1 for 2):**

I got

```
Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected freshly packed repo)
Note: when cloning local repositories, you need to pass
      --no-local to git clone to avoid this issue.
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed
anyway, use --force.
```

when executing

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-match "*:*"
```

**UPDATE2 for 2) :**

git clone --no-local /source/repo/path/ /target/path/to/repo/clone/

```
# Cloning into '/target/path/to/repo/clone'...
# remote: Enumerating objects: 9534, done.
# remote: Counting objects: 100% (9534/9534), done.
# remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4776/4776), done.
# remote: Total 9534 (delta 4216), reused 8042 (delta 3136), pack-reused 0
# Receiving objects: 100% (9534/9534), 7.40 MiB | 17.08 MiB/s, done.
# Resolving deltas: 100% (4216/4216), done.
```

git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-match "*:*"

```
# Parsed 591 commits
# New history written in 0.47 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
# Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
# HEAD is now at 501102d daily autocommit
# Enumerating objects: 9534, done.
# Counting objects: 100% (9534/9534), done.
# Delta compression using up to 8 threads
# Compressing objects: 100% (3696/3696), done.
# Writing objects: 100% (9534/9534), done.
# Total 9534 (delta 4216), reused 9534 (delta 4216), pack-reused 0
# Completely finished after 1.33 seconds.
```

git log --format="reference" --name-status --diff-filter=A "**/*:*"

```
# A    iscsi/nodes/iqn.2000-01.com.synology:NAS01-DS916.nas/ff11::111:11ff:ff1f:1ff1,3260,1/default
# ...
```

Unfortunately it seems filter-repo was executed, but log still lists filenames with colon :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log` to find all commits which have added specific files – this will result in a list of all files with names matching `*:*` across the history:

```
git log --format="" --name-status --diff-filter=A "**/*:*"
```

(`--format=` is used to hide the normal log output; alternatively `--oneline` might be useful):

Use `git filter-repo` to remove *or rename* such files across history:

- To remove:

  ```
  git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-match "*:*"
  ```
- To rename (e.g. change `:` to `;`):

  ```
  git filter-repo --filename-callback 'return filename.replace(b":", b";")'
  ```

git-filter-repo needs to be installed separately from git core.

Comment: `list of all files with names matching *:* across the history` means it lists all files in all branches having filename with colon?

Comment: The `git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-match "*:*"` resulted error. See the updated OP.